# Why do I get an undefined local variable or method error when using a constant, but not when using a method?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, constants

How come if I have a class like:

```
class Thing
  def number
    10
  end
end
```

And I inherit from it like this:

```
class OtherThing < Thing
  CONSTANT = number / 2
end
```

I get `undefined local variable or method 'number'` when I try to instantiate the class, but if I do this:

```
   class OtherThing < Thing
     def method_instead_of_constant
       number / 2
     end
   end
```

It works?

**EDIT**

I'm not necessarily looking for a hack to make this work, but an understanding as to why it doesn't. `mudasobwa`'s answer below helped the most; constants are assigned at the class level, not on instances.

Comment: Read up about `self` in Ruby... this will help you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a class method to achieve the functionality you are looking for:

```
class Thing
  #   ⇓⇓⇓⇓   HERE
  def self.number
    10
  end
end

class OtherThing < Thing
  CONSTANT = number / 2
end
```

`CONSTANT` assignment is happening on the class level, hence it has an access to class methods of `Thing`, but not to the instance methods of it.

On the other hand, you might instantiate `Thing` and then call the instance method on it:

```
class Thing
  def number
    10
  end
end

class OtherThing < Thing
  #          ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓  HERE
  CONSTANT = Thing.new.number / 2
end
```

Comment: I don't think the end goal is to define that constant that way. It's just an illustration to "this works, that doesn't"

Comment: Or maybe it is. Who knows :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I just dropped two examples, showing “what works, what does not” :)

Comment: Ahh I see, I didn't realise constants were made at the class level, I thought they were on each instance. Interesting thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because `number` is an instance method on `Thing`. The scope of the class definition of `OtherThing` is an instance of `Class`, which means it isn't an instance of `Thing` or an instance of `OtherThing` at definition.

That said, you shouldn't be defining constants by executing methods. You could presumably have a calculated class variable that you call `freeze` on to prevent editing post-startup, but even that's not a very common pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Because of scope.

Methods calls are evaluated based on the dynamic scope and distinguish between class and instance scope. Constants are resolved in lexical scope and do not distinguish between class and instance scope like methods do.

```
class A
  # expressions are evaluated in scope of class A
  def m
    # expressions are evaluated in scope of an instance of A
    return 42
  end
end
```

Class and instance are not the same.

```
A 
a = A.new

A.class # => Class
a.class # => A

A.respond_to?(:m) # => false
a.respond_to?(:m) # => true

A.m # => raises NoMethodError
a.m # => 42
```

Hence in the class body you cannot call instance methods.

Constants however are looked up using lexical scope, that is the surrounding context of classes and modules in the source file.

```
module M
  # can access global constants and those defined in M
  class A
    # can access global constants and those defined in M or A
    def m
      # can access global constants and those defined in M or A
    end
  end
end
```

You can inspect the current constant lookup path with `Module.nesting`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not necessarily looking for a hack to make this work, but and [sic]
>   understanding as to why it doesn't.

Here's the error message:

```
undefined local variable or method 'number'
```

When the Ruby interpreter sees `number` it looks for a local variable or a method named `number`. In the context of a method, the interpreter reads `number` as `self.number`. So this line:

```
CONSTANT = number / 2
```

is actually considered as:

```
CONSTANT = self.number / 2
```

**So what's `self`?**

Well that depends on where you've defined it (explicitly or implicitly). Within a class block, `self` is the class itself i.e. `OtherThing`. Since `OtherThing` nor any of its ancestors has a class-method `number` defined, nor does there exist a variable `number`, Ruby throws the error message.

`self` defined within an instance method definition is the current object. But this is awfully abstract without examples and some more theory. Other relevant topics are *Singleton-Classes* and *Inheritance*. If you like books, then I recommend *The Well-Grounded Rubyist 2nd Ed, Chapter 5* by *David A. Black*. On second thoughts, read/study the whole book.